# Reverse Resume Functionality for Safari

Tags: macos, safari, resume

I would like to reverse the resume keys for Safari. i.e.; Command-Q should quit and not save any tabs (since that is what I normally want to do). Cmd-Opt-Q should save windows.

I know I can disable resume system-wide.

I know I can use

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false
```

or other trickery (locking the saved state folder) to disable Resume per application.

In this case, I don't want to disable Resume for Safari, I just want it to reflect that 90% of the time, it isn't what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily done using the normal **Keyboard** system preference.

Go into the **Keyboard Shortcuts** section, then Applications, then Safari

Add the last two and you should be good to go...

[image]